# using TOP property and POSITION:ABSOLUTE

Tags: css

Just needing clarification: W3Schools partially defines the CSS "top" property (not margin- or padding-top) thusly:

> For absolutely positioned elements, the top property sets the top edge
>   of an element to a unit above/below the top edge of its containing
>   element.

NB: This is for "position:absolute" only.

I am confused by the "top edge of its containing element" part, because if I have the following structure (edited using the example on the "top" property provided by W3Schools):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
img
{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
}
.main { padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #000; }
.col { position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; }
.container { padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #000; }
.container2 { padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #000; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="main">
<div class="container">
<div class="test">
<p>Test</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container2">
<div class="col">
<img src="logocss.gif" width="95" height="84" />
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If its the "top edge of containing element" why is it that the image is at the top of the screen covering the "Test" text? I purposely nested two containing elements under the "main" , and to my mind the containing element would be "container2".

If I take out the "col" CSS, the image is still at the top of the screen but the  text is not.

Confused. :/

Comment: the parent element has to have `position: relative`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give .container2 a position, try this:

.container2 { padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #000; position:relative; }

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Marking as soon as the "10 minute" period is up :).

Comment: The container must have their `position` property set to either `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed`. If you want it to flow with the rest of the page, `relative` would be the proper one.

Comment: Everyone had the right answers, but @Jlegale was first. :) Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Thanks Rodin, I wanted to say that but couldn't find it anywhere to link to!

Answer (score 1):

I am bad at english, so please forgive me if I am now causing even more confusion, but `position:absolute` will position the element absolute in relation to the next relative element. In your case you dont have any element with the attribute `position:relative` and therefor it will position itself absolute in relation to the whole site (`html`).

What you would need to do in your case is giving `.container2` a `position:relative`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `position` the parent element correctly.

You're missing `position: relative` on the .container2 div

Here's a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cdrf7/)